# How can I view console logs in Ngrok?

Tags: ngrok

I am creating an ngrok server using the command: ngrok http 2567

In my application i'm doing various console.log calls and I'd like to be able to view them!

I have tried using ngrok help and using the --log flag, but with no luck.

How can I view my logs when hosting on ngrok?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to see the log from `ngrok` you should use `localhost:4040`, there is a list from all the requests you have done.

Comment: This only shows network requests not console.log as far as I can see

Answer (score 6):

Try running command: `./ngrok <http/https> <port_number> --log=stdout`

Ex: `./ngrok http 8080 --log=stdout`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use following command with **> ngrok.log &** to output ngrok logs into one file named **ngrok.log** (You can rename accordingly based on your need):

```
ngrok <http/https> <port_number> --log=stdout > ngrok.log &
```

After that, open **ngrok.log** to see logs details.